# Using character instead of String for single-character values in StringBuffer append

Tags: java, string, optimization, string-concatenation, pmd

I was going through the PMD rule `AppendCharacterWithChar`. It says *Avoid concatenating characters as strings in StringBuffer.append.*

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  // Avoid this
  sb.append("a");

  // use instead something like this
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append('a');
```

**Do I really need this PMD rule**? Is there much performance difference between the following two piece of code?

```
String text = new StringBuffer().append("some string").append('c').toString();

String text = new StringBuffer().append("some string").append("c").toString();
```

Comment: is there a good reason for you not to concat characters as characters or is it just curiosity?

Comment: I am implementing PMD check for my project. There are lots of places where people have used a single `string` instead of `char` in `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` append. Just wanted to know whether its worth the pain to correct 295 violation I got, or should I just ignore this rule.

Comment: so the reason is being lazy? In my opinion there's no excuse for not doing it the right way :-) you could use a script with regular expressions to fix it easily, maybe your IDE can do it for you? https://regex101.com/r/yN3dE2/1

Comment: I'll go ahead and use this PMD rule, cause if even though in a single statement it doesn't. If it is inside a loop it might matter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Appending a character as a `char` will always be faster than appending it as a `String`.

But does the performance difference matter? If you just do it once, it doesn't. If it is inside a cycle repeating its body a million times, then yes, it might matter.

If you already have the character at compile time, just append it as a character. If it is stored in a variable with `String` type, don't bother accessing it e.g. with `String.charAt(0)` or some other ways, simply just append the `String`.

**On a Side Note:**

Favor the [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class to [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). `StringBuilder` is faster because its methods are not synchronized (which you don't need in most cases).

**On a Side Note #2:**

This won't compile:

```
String text = new StringBuffer().append("some string").append('c');
```

`append()` returns `StringBuffer` for chaining. You need to call `toString()` on it:

```
String text = new StringBuffer().append("some string").append('c').toString();
```

Comment: As usual with these questions it goes: yeah, maybe, could be a performance gain. Make a benchmark on your system, get some proof, then decide how much effort it is worth putting in for your situation

Comment: Above one will violate another PMD rule https://pmd.sourceforge.io/pmd-4.3/rules/strings.html. AvoidStringBufferField says StringBuffers can grow quite a lot, and so may become a source of memory leak (if the owning class has a long life time).

Answer (score 5):

Out of curiosity I ran a micro benchmark with jmh (including GC monitoring). Using a String is marginally slower but the difference is minimal: around 5 ns (nanoseconds) per invocation and no significant difference on GC activity.

***If you called `append("c")` instead of `append('c')` one million times, it would add 5 ms to your program.***

Benchmark results, including gc time - `n` represents the initial length of the StringBuilder:

```
Benchmark                             (n)  Mode  Cnt     Score     Error   Units
SO28344.appendChar                      0  avgt   30    16.476 ±   0.331   ns/op
SO28343294.appendChar:·gc.time          0  avgt   30   256.000                ms
SO28343294.appendString                 0  avgt   30    22.048 ±   0.345   ns/op
SO28343294.appendString:·gc.time        0  avgt   30   220.000                ms

SO28343294.appendChar                  50  avgt   30    17.323 ±   0.967   ns/op
SO28343294.appendChar:·gc.time         50  avgt   30    67.000                ms
SO28343294.appendString                50  avgt   30    20.944 ±   1.466   ns/op
SO28343294.appendString:·gc.time       50  avgt   30    74.000                ms

SO28343294.appendChar                1000  avgt   30    58.396 ±   0.811   ns/op
SO28343294.appendChar:·gc.time       1000  avgt   30    25.000                ms
SO28343294.appendString              1000  avgt   30    64.572 ±   4.779   ns/op
SO28343294.appendString:·gc.time     1000  avgt   30    24.000                ms
```

Code:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class SO28343294 {

  @Param({"0", "50", "1000"}) int n;
  Random r = new Random();
  StringBuilder sb;
  String s;
  char c;

  @Setup(Level.Invocation) public void populate() {
    sb = new StringBuilder(n + 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      sb.append((char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
    }
    c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    s = new String(new char[] { c });
  }

  @Benchmark public StringBuilder appendString() {
    return sb.append(s);
  }

  @Benchmark public StringBuilder appendChar() {
    return sb.append(c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the implementation of each and compare them:

[`public AbstractStringBuilder append(char c)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#StringBuffer.append%28char%29):

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(char c) {
    int newCount = count + 1;
    if (newCount > value.length)
        expandCapacity(newCount);
    value[count++] = c;
    return this;
}
```

[`public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.append%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
    if (str == null) str = "null";
    int len = str.length();
    if (len == 0) return this;
    int newCount = count + len;
    if (newCount > value.length)
        expandCapacity(newCount);
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count = newCount;
    return this;
}
```

Which one do you prefer when you have the option to use both?

If I have 1000s of lines, I will really prefer to use `append(char c)` for better performances, but for one line, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its right **Avoid concatenating characters as strings in StringBuffer.append** because whenever you write `sb.append("a")` means you are creating a String object with value `a` and new String means new String object and  new String object in Stringpool and that means unnecessarily space accommodation in heap space.

Comment: `sb.append("a")` doesn't create new strings. String literals are interened.

Comment: but what if there is no string object with value 'a' ? will that create a new object in string pool ?

Comment: Yes, if it is not yet in the pool, it will be added to it. But since the `String` literal is part of the class definition, it might be added to the `String` pool when the class is loaded (implementation dependent).