# StringBuilder - Append 2 char's or 1 String

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

When working with a StringBuilder, I often append 2 char values to a StringBuilder  using `StringBuilder#append(char)` twice, rather than `StringBuilder#append(String)`.

I.e.:

```java
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.append(' ').append('t'); // would append(" t") work better here?
return builder.toString();
```

I would like to know:

- Which approach is better performance-wise
- Which approach is more common and why

I have already read through [Using character instead of String for single-character values in StringBuffer append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343294/using-character-instead-of-string-for-single-character-values-in-stringbuffer-ap) but it does not answer my question.

*That question* pertains to whether appending a single character (`append('c')`) is better than a single-character string (`append("c")`). I already understand why appending a single character is better than a single-character string, but I do not know whether appending a two-character string (`append("ab")`) is better than twice appending each character (`append('a').append('b')`).

Comment: It's hard to predict because there is JVM HotSpot between your code and CPU.
Your code probably will be optimized. 
That's why it's better to consider readability instead of performance.

Answer (score -1):

In my testing, both of them seemed to take about the same time, however appending a string might be *slightly* slower (maybe 10 or so nanoseconds)
However, appending a string is much more popular as it's easier to use/understand.

Answer (score -1):

This is really interesting to figure out this one.
As we all know the array is fast and internally String is using Character Array for storing the values.

internally both the method called the `super.append(XXX)` method of`AbstractStringBuilder`class.
if you see the code of append in AbstractStringBuilder for String and CharSeq

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
        if (str == null) str = "null";
        int len = str.length();
        ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
        str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
        count += len;
        return this;
    }
public AbstractStringBuilder append(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
        if (s == null)
            s = "null";
        if ((start < 0) || (start > end) || (end > s.length()))
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                "start " + start + ", end " + end + ", s.length() "
                + s.length());
        int len = end - start;
        ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
        for (int i = start, j = count; i < end; i++, j++)
            value[j] = s.charAt(i);
        count += len;
        return this;
    }
```

These are the method internally called when you call append method.
Both the method calls the `ensureCapacityInternal` method to expand the array. So let's leave this method call as it is.

Now, the main difference comes in the next line of code.
The method with String args calls the `getChars` method. which internally call the `System.arraycopy` method, it's a native method and we can't predict the complexity of that method. it's based on the OS/JVM.

CharSeq method uses a `for loop` till the length of input charSequence.

`for (int i = start, j = count; i < end; i++, j++)
            value[j] = s.charAt(i);`

i.e. it's completixity is depend on the length of input.

As I study, Other posts related to System.arraycopy method. They all say that it's effective than copying an array by a loop. even in an `Effective Java Programing` book.

So finally opinion, I would suggest that if the input is of small length then use the CharSequence only. Why waste the JVM for the small length String.

If you have long length string like a statement then go for a method with String args. Also, remember Space complexity increases in this case. i.e. String is immutable and you are creating more String every time in a pool. `String.valueof(), (String)obj` are examples.

Edited:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(char c) { ensureCapacityInternal(count + 1); value[count++] = c; return this; }
```

This method used when the args is char.
And seems that. It's more fast then others.
Because of assignment at count++ index of char. This method only contain the system.arraycopy method, which is common in all other method for ensuringcapacity.

Hope this will help. :)

Comment: It seems you are confusing the StringBuilder's various methods. AbstractStringBuilder#append(CharSequence, int, int) ≠ #append(char). The latter is only 3 LOC in my JVM and here. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java

Comment: Thanks. I missed it. I have added that one also